# How to read file containing UTF-8 hex encoded characters and then decode the characters to HTML hex numbers?

Tags: html, perl, unicode, utf-8, hex

I have a file containing UTF-8 hex encoded characters, as below:

```
<root>
<element>1 \xc3\x97 2 = 2</element>
</root>
```

I want to read the file and transform all the `\xhh` characters to the equivalent HTML hex numbers and then write to a new file. So, given a file with the above contents, the new file must look like:

```
<root>
<element>1 &#xd7; 2 = 2</element>
</root>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What format/encoding is your input file? Is it an XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you’ve used `:utf8` on the input stream, then this will fix the data:

```
s/([^\x00-\x7F])/sprintf "&#x%x;", ord $1/ge;
```